# Jackson Array serialize and de-serialize

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

My jackson string was the following,

```
{
"Response":{
   "users":[{"userId":"1", "userName":"User 1"},{"userId":"2", "userName":"User 1"}]
}
}

My classes are following,

public class Response {
   private List<User> users;
// getters and setters
}

public class User{
 private String userId;
 private String userName;

//getters and setters
}
```

When i tried to get the java object from the above json string. It gives me an following error. Any idea how to fix this?

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected START_OBJECT: need JSON Object to contain As.WRAPPER_OBJECT type information for class

Comment: You need one more class for example class ResponseJson { private Response response; }

Comment: You should Wrap Response in another object in this case to be able to deserialize such json.

Comment: Tried. That also gives me same error.

Comment: Could you add your code with mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more class wrapper:

```
class ResponseJson {
   @JsonProperty("Response")
   private Response response;
   // getters, setters 
}
```

Also you neeed this annotation @JsonPropery because jackson have some issue with uppercase field name details: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/249